# Phonegap: Where is the right cordova.js

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

i am trying arround with phonegap/cordova, but my problem is, that i want to add the device-motion plugin.

I did it with the cordova cli, so the CLI created the folder "org.apache.cordova.device-motion" in the plugins folder.

but where i get the right cordova.js file including this plugin? why the cli doesnt generate one? And i have the chrome extension to debug the app in my browser (without building) - but there is the same problem - where is the corodva.js?

Comment: You don't have to worry about that, just link it in your index.html and cordova will copy the right file to the right folder. BTW, it will be on yourprojectfolder/platforms/{platform}/platform_www

Comment: okay, but when i want to test the funcionality on my pc - as example the accelerometer functions?

Comment: add browser platform, or try on ripple instead of using the browser